# How many input splits a map task can process?

Tags: hadoop

My input file size is around 980 MB. Default Block size is 64 MB. So number of splits created for this input data set is 15 splits. As the number of splits is 15, the number of map tasks should be 15. In my case, both number of splits and map is 15. As per the hadoop concept, a map task processes just 1 input split. But in my case  each map task processes all 15 input splits. Could you tell me that why this is happening?

Comment: It should be 16 splits. You round up for partial splits

Comment: hi cricket_007, Could you tell me that what is rounding up partial splits? Each map task should process only one input split. but in my case, each map task is processing all 16 input splits. So, i am not getting expected output.

Comment: Your question said 15 splits. 980/64 is more than 15, so it should be 16 splits. That's all. I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, though. You are seeing  16*16=256 map tasks? Because you said "both number of splits and map is 15", which is correct if there were 15 splits. If both numbers are the same, then there is one map task per split